# Windows 8.1 Hosted Network has No Internet Access

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet, windows-8.1, connection-sharing

I'm attempting to share my laptop's WiFi connection with another computer through an Ethernet cable. I've so far followed [this guide](http://4sysops.com/archives/how-to-share-wi-fi-in-windows-8-with-internet-connection-sharing-ics/) to ensure my laptop supports hosted networks and to create a new hosted network.

However, this network itself has no internet access, meaning when I do share it with the Ethernet connection my other computer ends up with no IP address (and is ultimately offline).

[image: Screenshot of issue]

Unfortunately the only help I can find for this issue is [this question](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/66946699-65c4-44eb-8755-c9355aa7aec8/no-internet-access-through-win-8-hosted-network?forum=w8itpronetworking) which for whatever reason has an accepted answer pointing to the guide I linked to above (and doesn't at all answer the question).

What can I do to give my hosted network internet access?

Comment: This question is based on a lot of misunderstandings that make it impossible to answer. For example, what does internet access have to do with getting assigned an IP address?

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [Internet Connection Sharing ( ICS ) not working in Windows 8 CP](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/88613e70-8baa-4b6a-977a-4e2f9b252317/internet-connection-sharing-ics-not-working-in-windows-8-cp?forum=W8ITProPreRel):

Set ICS service start mode to auto (delayed):

- *Run* » `services.msc` » Internet Connection Sharing » Startup Type » auto (delayed)
- Restart your PC or stop/start the service.

This service will load after Windows starting in about 5 minutes (on i7 960), it does not immediately start.

Second solution to make ICS work on start up:

- Go to Run » `services.msc` but then, aside from checking ICS service, check for "Routing and Remote Access". If it's on manual you need to set it to *automatic – delayed* and turned on.
- By default it was turned off, not even on manual mode.
- After I changed it to *Automatic* and pressed *Start*, Internet started working.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! It's not encouraged to just copy-paste solutions [you found somewhere else](http://www.eightforums.com/network-sharing/36861-no-internet-access-through-hosted-network-windows-8-1-a.html) without proper attribution.  Please always cite your sources or paraphrase the content.